# Add values in a row based on the date values in a sepperate row

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to calculate the overtime that has accrued up to and including today's date.

**Sample Data**

- Row 2 contains a list of dates.
- Row 3 the time worked for each date.
- Row 4 the accrued overtime for each date.

[image: example data]

The following formula in `I6` should return the SUM of accrued overtime on or before   TODAY():

```
=SUM(HLOOKUP(FILTER(C2:GB2, C2:GB2 <= TODAY()), C2:GB4, 3))
```

In my example the formula in `I6` shaded red should return `5` (the SUM of `C4:I4`) but instead it returns `1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

One of the easiest solutions is to put in cell **I6** the formula `=SUMIF(C2:I2,"<=" &TODAY(),C4:I4)` and repeat this for every week

Answer (score 0):

Using SUMIF as [suggested by @JohnSUN](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/168141/) is a good approach and also slightly shorter (4 chars) than the alternative below.

Your original approach would work if you tweak it to FILTER row 4 based on the date in row 2, then SUM the resulting array:

```
=SUM(FILTER(
   C4:GB4, C2:GB2<=TODAY()))
```